# AFNetworking get baseurl of string and the path

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I receive a `URL` that I need to send `HTTP POST` to. This `URL` is dynamic, it can change. For example, here's one `URL`

```
https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/jhess2991/image/upload
```

I am using `AFNetworking`, which requires a `baseURL` and a `path` to perform any `HTTP` action. In this particular case, the `baseURL` would be `https://api.cloudinary.com` and `path` would be `/v1_1/jhess2991/image/upload`

I am wondering if there's a way I can dynamically retrieve `baseURL` and `path` from a `URL` string and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There is `baseURL` property for retrieving the base url from an `NSURL` object.

Also you can use the `path` property for getting the path.

```
NSURL *baseUrl    = [nsurlObj baseURL];
NSString *path    = [nsurlObj path];
```

Please refer [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path)

Comment: Calling baseURL on 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/jhess2991/image/upload' returns nil

Answer (score 0):

By using `[url scheme]`and`[url host]` like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somesite.com/bar/baragain"];
NSLog(@"Base url: %@://%@", [url scheme], [url host]);
// output is http://www.somesite.com
```